# Second mould when Stormbreaker is cast, what's in it?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, stormbreaker

From the movie Infinity War, this shot clearly shows two moulds being filled during the casting of Stormbreaker:

[image: Shot of two streams of metal filling two moulds.]

After Eitri thumps the mould three times, both halves are seen amid the pieces of one mould:

[image: Two pieces of Stormbreaker glowing amidst mould fragments/]

Do we have any indication from movie cannon, comic, or press statements as to what might have been in the second mould? (Eg. Love and Thunder spoilers?)

<sup>Both pictures taken as screenshots copyright Marvel studio's Avengers: Infinity War 2018, fair usage.</sup>

Comment: A handle for the axe? Only he had no time to open it, forcing Groot to interfere?

Comment: Anyone have any in-universe evidence to support their position?

Comment: Not really, no. Although... It is possible that more molds were filled. It was a forge world, with multiple things being forged at the same time and multiple projects being worked on by multiple dwarven craftsmen. The energy source was turned off and all those forges stopped. Just flipping the switch on would make them start again.

Comment: Hands for Eitri?

Answer (score 8):

One piece is the axe (say “front”), and the other is the hammer piece (say “back”); they each are shaped slightly differently.

Groot then draws these two separate pieces together with his arm to create Stormbreaker, after Eitri is unable to locate the handle he originally might have had in mind.

Comment: We only see Eitri emptying the one mould onto the floor, and only the three thumps on the one mould are heard - when does he break the other mould, and how does he get the pieces together (if they're from separate moulds) without the use of hands?

Comment: I was looking for in-universe footage or narrative from the comics, as reasonable as your inductive logic might be, it doesn't provide the evidence. (I upvoted anyhow).

Comment: I've downvoted this answer, from what we see on screen I don't see how this is correct. Eitri knocks one mould onto the ground which breaks releasing one half and then smashes the unbroken segment to release the second half. I only count one mould being broken.

Comment: Well, are we even certain what the other thing is? What is source for question it even is a second mold and not something like an overflow receptacle to catch waste material?

Comment: @SillybutTrue It could be overflow, and that would be a valid answer to this question. The question is just assuming that it's a mould.

Comment: This is the answer. The hammer was forged in two pieces and each piece would need its own opening to pour metal into. Technically it's one mold with two openings producing two pieces. Eitri then pulls out the whole thing and smashes it open, releasing both pieces.

Comment: @kenster There isn't enough room in that mold for 2 pieces of that size.  And the other pouring location looks a lot like this mold.  It makes more sense that they simply cut the breaking of the 2nd mold.

Comment: I think "front" and "back" are ambiguous, as they depend on a particular orientation of the axe. Perhaps "axe side" and "hammer side" would be more clear.

Comment: “I poured my metal into both the holes, if you know what I mean.”

Comment: @Yakk the point is that when you see metal being poured into two holes, one hole is for the axe part and the other is for the hammer part. The thing that Eitri throws to the floor and punches is a single mold containing both parts. Eitri is a big guy and the mold looks small by comparison.

Comment: @Kenster That is not consistent with the appearance of what Eitir throws to the floor.  It looks exactly like the thing around one of the two holes.  I mean, we have a video, you can look at it.

Comment: 1:22 the pour, 1:44 throwing to the ground (one, not two).  Note the size of the corners.  2:02 axe pieces; you can also see a corner of the original mold.  This looks to me that there wouldn't be enough space for both pieces in that mold, given how big the axe head pieces are compared to the original mold.

Comment: @Yakk I'll add that the mold is laying on its side when Eitri throws it to the floor. During the pour the square faces were two of the sides, and the holes would be on one of the rectangular faces. The mold looks big enough to me.

Comment: @kenster Huh?  Are you looking at tge same video?  We can see the distinctly shaped corners; the pour has the square face up with a hole.  We can see how big those corners are.  We can see them when Eitri throws it to the floor.  We later see the same corners sitting next to the axe head on the floor  broken.  I am boggled by "the holes would be in one of the rectangular faces", we see in video the fluid flowing into a square face.

Answer (score 8):

Probably mold for the handle of the axe?

In the scene, Eitri says.

> "He needs the axe. Where's the handle? Tree! Help me find the handle!"

Looks right in growing panic then.

[image: Eitri goes left]

... goes to his left, where the second mold was shown in the previous scene.

Then Groot sees that axe head is cooling down, intervenes and provides a handle.

Comment: @SillybutTrue Well, his king (and only hope to defeat Thanos) is dying and he just finished getting the axe-head out of the mold. He was so focused on "the important part of the axe" that he forgot "the unimportant" one. Btw, in the original forging of Mjolnir, due to Loki's interference in shape of a fly, the handle ended up shorter than it should have been.  It should have been two-handed axe. I guess it is just a thing with Eitri and handles. :)

Comment: Well, two-handed axe for the Stormbreaker, two-handed war hammer for Mjolnir.